Expected name collision behavior between 2GP managed package and 2GP unlocked package with same namespace
I am trying to understand the expected behavior for the following scenario:
Under the same dev hub, I have developed a pair of 2G packages. Both of them share the same namespace (myns):
Package A: 2GP, Managed, Namespace (myns)
Package B: 2GP, Unlocked, Namespace (myns)
Package A has exposed a class (MyTestClass) with the @NamespaceAccessible annotation.
While developing "Package B" in a (myns) namespaced scratch org that has Package A installed, I noticed I am able to also create a class called MyTestClass. Wasn't sure what to expect. However, it seems like its not overriding the same class in the managed package. It also seems like I can't edit its contents from the dev console or the Org's apex editor. I tried to search for expected behavior in the documentation but couldn't find anything clear on it. Seems like the safe way to go with packages that share namespaces is to avoid class name collisions because the platform won't handle those automatically.

Actually it does seem to override the managed package class, but then I have no way to undo it since I can't delete the class. So just something to keep in mind if you're doing this. I had to create a new scratch org to fix this.
